# PHP MySQL - Show parent categories with subcategories as count

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the below two MySQL tables.

USERS TABLE

```
-----------------------------
user_id      category_id
-----------------------------
  1      |    101,115,138
  2      |    113,102,107
  3      |    156,101,133
  4      |    123,144,151
  5      |    122,114,116
```

CATEGORIES TABLE

```
-----------------------------
category_id    |    parent   
-----------------------------
    101        |      0      
    113        |     101
    114        |     101            
    115        |     101      
    116        |     101      
    102        |      0      
    123        |     102
    103        |      0      
    133        |     103
    138        |     103
```

and so on.....

I want to show only the main categories found in the USERS TABLE with a count of the number of users it and its sub categories has.

Below is the result im looking for,

```
101(6) //This is 6 users because its 101,115,113,101,114,116 in USERS TABLE
102(2) //This is 2 users because its 102,122 in USERS TABLE
103(2) //This is 2 users because its 133,138 in USERS TABLE
```

and so on...

This is what im currently trying

```
$sqlg1='SELECT * FROM USERS_TABLE";';
        $resg1 = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlg1) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
        while($rowg1 = mysqli_fetch_array($resg1))
        {
            $countcats=0;
            $categoryids = $rowg1['category'];
            $categoryidsall = explode(',',$categoryids);                
            foreach($categoryidsall as $categoryid) 
            {                        
                $sqlg2='SELECT * FROM CATEGORIES_TABLE WHERE category_id="'.$categoryid.'";';
                $resg2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlg2) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));                    
                while($rowg2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resg2))
                {
                    $chkparent = $rowg2['parent'];
                }

                if($chkparent!=0)
                {
                    $categoryid= $chkparent;
                    $countcats++;                    
                }
                else
                {
                    $countcats=1;
                }

                echo $categoryid.'('.$countcats.')';

            }
```

Please help me out how do i get the required output!

Comment: WOW.. Nobody can help me?

Comment: Come on - surely you know what's wrong here. It's fundamental to relational database design

Comment: See normalisation

Comment: Hi @Strawberry. CAn you be more specific. this is the database we have to stick around and im trying many ways to get the result. Would greatly appreciate if you can guide a path. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a normalised relationship, so the idea that you *have to stick* with it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Edit your question and show a sample of the expected result. @Strawberry is right about the normalization, but I've also been stuck with some previous work that doesn't make sense. One suggestion would be to accumulate a list of categories (unique list of keys) and do the lookups after going through the whole list of users. You may be doing the same lookups many times instead of doing them just once for each id,